# Proof that the language $ww^R$ is not regular without using the pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

I am breaking my head over this. Let the alphabet $A$ be given by 
$A = \{a,b,c\}$ and let

$$L = \{ww^R \mid w \in A^* \}.$$

Prove that the language $L$ is not regular **without using the pumping lemma**, but using:

- The fact that $\{a^nb^n \in A^* \mid n \geq 0 \}$ is not regular.
- The fact that $\{w \in A^* \mid w \text{ is a palindrome} \}$ is not regular.
- Closure properties of the class of regular languages (such as if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are regular, then $L_1 \cup L_2$ is also regular, etc.).

Comment: $L$ consists of the even length palindromes.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$ L_1 = \{\ \omega\omega^r \ | \ \omega \in \Sigma^* \} $$
$$ L_2 = \{\ a^nb^n \ | \ n \in \mathbb{N}\ \}$$

Because $\Sigma = \{a, b, c\}$ is finite, $\Sigma^*$ must be countable.

This means we can define a function $f : \Sigma^* \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ which returns the position of a word $\omega \in \Sigma^*$ in an arbitrary ordering defined by $f$. $f$ is invertible, we define $f^{-1} : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \Sigma^*$, which returns the word $\omega$ at position $n$ in the enumeration of $\Sigma^*$ as defined by $f$.

Now, since every word $\omega$ is uniquely defined by a natural number $n$, and every word $\omega$ has exactly one unique reverse $\omega^r$, we can define an isomorphism between $L_1$ and $L_2$:

$$ g \colon\  L_1 \rightarrow L_2; \quad \omega\omega^r \mapsto a^{f(\omega)}b^{f(\omega)} $$

$$ g^{-1} \colon \ L_2 \rightarrow L_1; \quad a^nb^n \mapsto f^{-1}(n) f^{-1}(n)^r $$

Since $L_2$ is not regular and we have a bijection between $L_1$ and $L_2$, $L_1$ must not be regular.

This proof works for any finite alphabet $\Sigma$ because the transitive closure of a finite alphabet is always countable.

Comment: "isomorphism"? You meant bijection. It does not work; otherwise we can show $\{\ a^n \mid n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ is not regular since we can build an "isomorphism" between it and $L_2$ easily.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Yes, I meant bijection. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $L$ is regular. Then $L' = L \cap (a+b)^*c^2(a+b)^*$ is also regular. Another description for $L'$ is
$$ L' = \{ wccw^R : w \in (a+b)^* \}. $$
Consider now the regular substitution $\sigma$ given by
$$
\sigma(a) = \{a\}, \sigma(b) = \{b\}, \sigma(c) = \{a,b,\epsilon\}.
$$
Then $L'' = \sigma(L')$ is also regular. But $L''$ is the language of palindromes.